# Anchor <a> con un enlace, se activa automáticamente cuando se envía un correo con template HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email

Estoy enviando un correo basado en una plantilla HTML, el cual tiene dos enlaces:

Plantilla:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .link {
            padding: 8px 12px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgb(25, 123, 214);
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div
        style="border: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230); height: auto; margin: 20px; padding: 25px; box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px rgb(160, 160, 160);">
        <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-top: 3pt solid rgb(25, 123, 214);">
            <br />
            <p style="font-size: 20px;">Estimado %%departamento%%,</p>
            <br />
            <p>Se hace de su conocimiento que el GNP con número %%id%% y un monto total de %%ammount%%, ha sido
                levantado.</p>
            <p>Operador: %%num_operador_zam%% %%operator_name%%</p>
            <p>Viaje: %%idtravelzam%%</p>
            <p>Origen: %%origin%%</p>
            <p>Destino: %%destination%%</p>
            <p>Comentarios: %%operatorComment%%</p>
            <p>Fecha: %%created_at%%</p>
            <p>Tipo: %%cNonBudgetedExpenseType%%</p>
            <p>%%sensores%%</p>
            <p>Estatus: %%cNonBudgetedExpenseStatus%%</p>
            <p><img src="%%evidenciaUrl%%" alt="evidencia" width="400" height="400"></p>
            <p>Responda a esta solicitud:</p>
            <p>
                <span><a class="link" href="%%urlAccept%%" target="_blank">Aceptar</a></span>
                <span><a class="link" href="%%urlRefuse%%" target="_blank">Rechazar</a></span>
            </p>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">Nota: Este correo se envía de forma automática, no es necesario responderlo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando yo remplazo las variables **%%urlAccept%%** y **%%urlRefuse%%** , por los enlaces correspondientes , estos enlaces harán una funcionalidad cuando el usuario le dé click.

Los enlaces son servicios api como el siguiente:

> http://IPPUBLIC/api/viajes/nonBudgetedExpense/verify/email?status=0&gnpid=5650&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiIxMzc2IiwiUGFzc3dvcmQiOiJDOTc1M0E0MiIsIkVtYWlsIjoidmVyaWZ5QHNvZnRtLmNvbS5teCIsIlVzZXJJZENvbmZpcm1hdGlvbiI6IjEzNjMiLCJuYmYiOjE2NTUzMTM1NzUsImV4cCI6MTY1NTM1Njc3NSwiaWF0IjoxNjU1MzEzNTc1fQ.3IzA62gJHYanGtYIGuCq2YQdGZBB_GYWTBCSydPF9dw

Por ejemplo el recurso con el número gnpid=565 del enlace está en un estatus NUEVO, entonces cuando el usuario dé click en la opción **ACEPTAR** o **RECHAZAR** el recurso gnpid=565 pasa al estatus que dio click el usuario.

Problema: Es cuando el correo llega a la aplicación del correo cliente, estos enlaces como que se activan automáticamente haciendo la funcionalidad del enlace. Sí, antes que el usuario pueda darle click a la opción.

Los correos clientes que he probado es:
Outlook Desktop
outlook.live.com

Código del cliente para enviar correo:

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient Smtpclient = new SmtpClient(configuracionCorreo.OutgoingServer);

                mail.From = new MailAddress(configuracionCorreo.User);

                foreach (var item in mailsTo)
                {
                    mail.To.Add(item);
                }


                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.Body = strHtmlBody;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
                {
                    mail.CC.Add(cc);
                }

                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


                Smtpclient.Port = Int32.Parse(configuracionCorreo.OutgoingPort.ToString());
                Smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(configuracionCorreo.User, configuracionCorreo.Password);
                Smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                            delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                              X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                            { return true; };

                //Se envia los datos
                Smtpclient.Send(mail);
```

Codigo que utilizo para remplazar mis parametros:

```
 private string ReplaceDynamicHtmlInformation(dynamic dataObject, TemplateCorreo templateCorreo)
        {
            var body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(templateCorreo.Body);

            //se obtienen las macros dentro del contenido
            string pattern = @"\%\%(\w+)\%\%";
            Regex rg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

            MatchCollection collection = rg.Matches(body);

            foreach (var match in collection)
            {
                string key = match.ToString().Replace("%%", "");
                var dataValue = ((IDictionary<String, Object>)dataObject).Where(d => d.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();

                if (dataValue.Key == null)
                    throw new Exception("No se encontró en el objeto de datos la propiedad '" + key + "' que corresponde a una macro definida dentro del template.");

                body = body.Replace(match.ToString(), dataValue.Value.ToString());
            }

            return body;
        }
```

¿Saben cómo prevenir esto hasta que el usuario le dé click?

Comment: Está raro el escenario, edita la pregunta y agrega todo el código que sea necesario para reproducir tu caso, así evitamos ir a ciegas y/o estar en modo entrevista. Incluye los clientes de correo electrónico que has probado, también los logs del servidor de cuando se ha ejecutado la acción. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @fredyfx , ya edite la pregunta. Espero tengas alguna idea. Si los templeates HTML deben llevar una directiva o tratarse de manera diferente, o que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿Cómo reemplazas los valores? Sospecho que en ese momento es donde se ejecutan, por cierto, intenta cambiar `%%variable%%` por algo diferente como `##variable##` y a ver qué sale.

Comment: //Se forma el enlace para cada usuario al que llegara el correo, para aceptar o rechazar la solicitud
                templeatedata.urlAccept = $"{approvalNbe.Value}?status={(int)ApprovalNBE.Accept}&gnpid={nonBudgetedExpenseId}&token={token}";
                templeatedata.urlRefuse = $"{approvalNbe.Value}?status={(int)ApprovalNBE.Refuse}&gnpid={nonBudgetedExpenseId}&token={token}";

                emailResponse = notificationSender.SendMail(email, templeatedata, templateCorreo);

Comment: Acabo de enviar el comentario como se remplazan, pero no creo que sea como se remplazan,  porque estoy monitoreo el recurso en la base de datos y cuando el correo me notifica que el correo llego. Es cuando este se cambio de estatus :/. Ya hice esas validaciones. La verdad no se que este ocacionando eso. O si tengo que cambiar algo en la plantilla o en el codigo C# del envio del correo. No encuentro algo como tal.

Comment: De pura o simple casualidad ¿tienes un antivirus o alguna solución de seguridad que se encargue de monitorear todos los enlaces entrantes/salientes en el servidor de correo?

Comment: Tendré que validar, accesos al correo son lo que expone el cliente del proyecto. Y desconozco la configuración. Muchas gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137135/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-alexander-morales).

Comment: ¿Alguna novedad?

Comment: Que tal fredyfx, pense que habia contestado en el chat. Con la sugerencia que me comentastes , se opto por hacer un pequeño front para onseguir esta funcionalidad.

Comment: Vale, me alegra saber que ya tienes esa feature en camino. Ahora toca cerrar la pregunta porque sencillamente no se puede reproducir tu escenario debido a que se desconoce la causa, sospecho que un motor de antivirus/firewall está monitoreando cada enlace. Saludos.